# Use annotation in springMVC class diagram

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, class-diagram

I am designing a class diagram for Java Spring MVC web application. 
I didnt find any material to use annotations like @Controller, @Service, @Autowired like these in class diagram.

Without this my class diagram generates very plain java code without spring annotation.

Anyone please help me use this in class diagram if possible.

Answer (score 0):

couple of ways to represent annotations discussed here : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280069/how-can-attributes-annotations-be-illustrated-on-a-uml-class-diagram

But you need to check your code generator documentation for how this will be interpreted to generate the annotations in your code.